# How to check if client is local in Java

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have a server-side application running Apache Tomcat and developed with Spring. I need to prevent some users to access the application outside the local network.
I've been searching for a while, but I couldn't find a way to solve this. Does Spring provide a functionality to restrict the user internal/external access based on his permissions?

Answer (score 5):

The servlet spec allows you to view the remote IP address, `ServletRequest#getRemoteAddr()`. The conventional way to restrict access by IP address is using a **servlet filter** to whitelist or blacklist IP address ranges. You can search for a servlet filter implementation which you could add to your spring app. You would just need to configure it. BUT... ensure the implementation your choose accounts for the following. And if you can't find one which accounts for this, consider writing your own.

The major point to be aware of, is that the "*remote address*" as seen by your server is **not guaranteed to identify the client machine at all**. This is a networking issue as opposed to a Spring/servlet issue. The remote address your server sees, might even be the IP of a load balancer or other network device on your own internal network.

Read about HTTP header [X-Forwarded-For](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-forwarded-for). If a reverse proxy, or load balancer in some configurations, on your internal network forwards a request at application layer in the TCP/IP stack (e.g. HTTP), and so changes the origin IP as seen by your server, in the case of HTTP that device will often include or add the original IP to this header. In fact this header can contain a *list* of original IP addresses, in the case that the request passed through *several* NATs or proxies in the originating organization or en-route on the internet before reaching your own network.

I'd recommend conservative white-listing of *allowed* addresses, instead of black-listing forbidden addresses for sure. If your network architecture changed this could be more robust, but you'd still need to be careful if re-assigning IPs on your internal network.

Your servlet filter could use a combination of `ServletRequest#getRemoteAddr()` and parsing the `X-Forwarded-For` header.

Also remember to include any IPv6 addresses in your design and whitelist or blacklist.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Web security exception with `hasIpAddress(String)` when using XML expression

[link: 15.2 Web Security Expressions](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html#el-access-web)

Comment: Looks like a good solution, but since I'm using the standard security notations, it would be complicated change to expression notations.
I'm aware that I can declare WebSecurityExpressionRoot as a bean, but I'm not sure about the arguments I should use in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Spring, but, assuming you have access to Tomcat's config files, you can set up a `Valve` in the configuration files of either Tomcat itself or particular webapps to filter access based on IP address.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_Address_Filter
http://vicker313.wordpress.com/2010/11/05/restrict-ip-coming-to-tomcat-service/